# google lat lng not being returned consistently for an address

Tags: latitude-longitude, google-places-api

i am using the following javascript code and it was working. suddenly, it started returning only the longitude and the latitude was null.

Why am I getting this kind of sporadic response ? Any clue ?

```
var place = search.autocomplete.getPlace();

$('#lat').val(place.geometry.location.$a);
$('#lng').val(place.geometry.location.ab);
```

EDIT:
on printing the place, I see that "$a" got changed to "ab" and "ab" got changed to "cb". surprise. How do I take care of this, if they change it in future again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are internal variables that you should not directly access. Please use the [documented methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) instead.

For example:

```
var place = search.autocomplete.getPlace();

$('#lat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
$('#lng').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
```